# SPAN element becomes block level on show() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I created two demos:

Demo 1: http://jsfiddle.net/DqvTa/7/
Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/DqvTa/8/

The demos are almost identical. The only difference is that I set `#span { display:none; }` in demo 1 and `span { display:none; }` in demo 2.

Could someone explain why the SPAN element - in demo 2 - becomes a block-level element?

---

My assumption is that (during `show()`) jQuery internally creates a SPAN element to check whether it is naturally an inline or block-level element. But since I set all SPANs to `display:none` in demo 2, jQuery is unable to determine that.

---

btw the ticket is here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8099

Comment: I can't think of any reason other than the fact that jQuery does not know what you want it to become, block or inline. So it just settles for the most likely. It would be a good feature to be able to specify what you want it to become. *jots it in the todo for his library*

Comment: You're assumption sounds fair. I'm trying to find a non-compressed form of jquery to check. Their download page is returning a sql error at the moment though. :)

Comment: look at the homepage: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js

Comment: @ahmed: Ah thanks for that. That'll teach me to go straight to the download page without looking elsewhere. :)

Comment: Look in the defaultDisplay function. That is where it does exactly what you suggest (adds the element to the body, checks its display property and then removes it - if the display property is none or "" then it sets it to block. I suspsect this would therefore happen for any element hidden like this (eg anchors - http://jsfiddle.net/CA9JF/).

Comment: [Yes, you're right.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/effects.js#L509-516) It would be nice if jQuery included a map of non-block types it could reference, but I suppose they don't want the added bulk.

Comment: It looks like they promoted your ticket to blocker. Looks like a bug needing fixed...

Comment: And possibly the maintenance of it as well since new elements may not get added and also some elements have different types in different browsers (eg older browsers that didn't know about the various table display types). Maybe they'll just create a new dom to stick this in to test it which will be unpoluted by stylesheets. Also I suspect that setting the display globally for a single element type is a bit of a code smell anyway.

Comment: @Chris Yea,  `type { display:none }` should be avoided then.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: I'd actually personally avoid any CSS that relied solely on tag names. Even if it meant I had one class that was on every tag of one type and no other I'd still prefer that so that if I ever did want an unstyled version of that tag I wouldn't have to worry about changing my stylesheets around and retesting everything. :)

Comment: @Chris I tend to only style body and h1 by type (because they're unique on the page). In this particular case, I was writing a demo for another question on SO - in such demos I usually avoid ID and class attributes and select by type instead (so that the demo is simple and readable).

Comment: @Šime Vidas: i try to make button and set toggle method for show and hide span(I check attribute's changing in Firebug). In your demo 2 span element is set to none so jQuery .show() method read the previous state of span element when DOM load to browser if element state before shown is none jQuery show method can't detect it, and show it in state none not inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been identified as a bug. The ticket is here:
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8099

Answer (score 2):

That's a bug, right. 
But you can do `$('span').css('display', 'inline');`  rather than `$('span').show();`

Answer (score 1):

This is because, .show(), is like a display block except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially.

jQuery use a propertry called olddisplay in the node that you modify with show (you can see it with FireQuery), if you modify the box model of the span, (not the #span) jquery dont recognice the correct old display mode of the node

Comment: Not quite true. I haven't got the code in front of me but I believe that initially like this olddisplay won't be set at all and therefore it will call the defaultDisplay function to find the default display type for the node. See the comments above for discussion on this.

Comment: This issue has been identified on jQuery's bug tracker - check out the ticket in my question.